# Why can't I put a source image in my Image component?

Tags: unity

I can't put an image here as source image, and I have trouble figuring out why.

What did I miss?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay. Is there a question you wanted to ask, or did you just want to let us know what's up?

Comment: Is there a reason you upload a picture instead of a desktop screenshot, taken with your OS? (These would make the image much more clear.)

Comment: Are you sure the image you are trying to apply is a **SPRITE**? When you click on your image file asset (Project tab), make sure the **Texture Type** is set to **Sprite (2D and UI)**

Comment: is a image into a Panel, and the image I drag from pc to unity, but when I want to ser like walpaper o image of other element, I can't.   btw....I toke a cellphone photo, because if I take a screenshoot, the mouse can't see.....I upload another picture, where my images dont show in the assets

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have the editor settings configured for 3D defaults.

This means that when you import a new image file into your project, Unity assumes by default that you want to use it as a Texture asset, for texturing 3D models, skyboxes, etc. or using as a shader input.

But for UI, you want to treat that image as a Sprite. This packs the image data in a particular way that's efficient for the UI rendering system, and includes metadata for common 2D/UI operations.

To mark your images as Sprites, select them in the Project assets browser, and the Inspector window will update to show the images' import settings.

In the Texture Type drop-down at the top, select "Sprite (2D and UI)" then hit Apply. Your images should now show up as selectable for UI Image components and SpriteRenderers

[image: Texture settings]

Comment: Yes, was that, I didn't check that step, thanks a lot